# The problem of automatic translation of language when web crawling using BeautifulSoup in visual studio environment

Tags: python, visual-studio, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

In *visual studio* environment, if I turn off the headless option, it doesn't translate automatically. but if I use headless option, the language is automatically converted.

It seems to be a *visual studio* problem as it is not automatically translated in *google colab*.

**How can I use it without automatic translation in a visual studio environment?**
(I don't use chrome extensions. and chrome version: 97.0.4692.71, VS19)

Comment: I solved it by adding the option below.
`add_argument("--lang=en")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the option below.

```
add_argument("--lang=en")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/headless-dev/c/BXy9fZvVBO8?pli=1

This could be helpful, it states that it is not possible, however i would check myself.